# How can I compare array with same index and value

Tags: javascript

How can I compare this two array or check that if it is same index and same value

**example: not equal**

```
var a = [310,311,312];

var b = [312,311,310];
```

**example: equal**

```
var a = [310,311,312];

var b = [310,311,312];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hopefully we'll soon get [`Array.prototype.equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590182)

Comment: Use `every`: `a.every((e,i)=>e==b[i])`

Comment: @gorak Also need to check lengths are identical. Also, don't use sloppy comparison - strict equality is better. Or, if NaN is a possible value (or 0 needs to be distinguished from -0), `Object.is` is better

Comment: You can also do strings comparison console.log(a.toString() === b.toString())

Comment: @AbhijeetAbnave when you do -0 to `toString()` it becomes `'0'`. `Object.is` is much better choice.

Comment: @gorak agree with your points, thanks for letting me know